# Can someone explain this snippet of magento code?

Tags: php, magento

could some one please explain this snippet of magento code found in `loadByCustomerId()` in the class `Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Quote`.

```
$read = $this->_getReadAdapter();
$select = $this->_getLoadSelect('customer_id', $customerId, $quote)
                ->where('is_active=1')
                ->order('updated_at desc')
                ->limit(1);
$data = $read->fetchRow($select);
```

When i `var_dump($data)` i see that its an array of customer data. What is model associated with this `$data` array? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Magento "Models" (meaning the entities that allow you to interact with the database, not general purpose server/domain models) have two layers.  The first is the "Model" layer.  This contains methods for logical interactive with an model.  (get me a customer's address, place the order, etc).  The second layer is the "Resource Model" layer.  Resource Models handle any interactive with the database (or,more generally, the data-store,or the persistance layer, or etc.).

The way a Resource Model interacts with the database is via adapter objects.  One for reading information, another for writing information.

So, you're in the class `Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Quote`.  This is a Resource Model.  It's the backend for the `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote` object, instantiated with

```
$model = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
```

With this line

```
$read = $this->_getReadAdapter();
```

you're getting a reference to the model's **read** adapter.  This will let you make queries to the database.

With this line

```
$select = $this->_getLoadSelect('customer_id', $customerId, $quote)
                ->where('is_active=1')
                ->order('updated_at desc')
                ->limit(1);
```

You're getting a reference to the SQL statement (also an object) that this Resource Model will use to load a `sales/quote` object.

```
//gets a reference
$this->_getLoadSelect('customer_id', $customerId, $quote)
```

Then, you're calling methods on that object to alter it with additional logic

```
->where('is_active=1')
->order('updated_at desc')
->limit(1);
```

In pseudo sql, a query might look like this normally

```
SELECT * FROM quote_table;
```

But after you call those methods, the query will look something like

```
SELECT * FROM quote_table
WHERE is_active = 1
ORDER BY updated_at desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Finally,

```
$data = $read->fetchRow($select);
```

here you're using the read adapter you fetched earlier to make a query into the database for the specific quote item row that your query will fetch.

Comment: How to print this query ?

Answer (score 2):

`_getReadAdapter()` gets the read-only database connection. `_getLoadSelect` creates a select query on the model's (Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Quote) main table. The data returned is just raw data from the SQL query not associated with any particular backend model.

Comment: so '_getLoadSelect' indirectly creates a new row in the sales_flat_quote table? I need to create a new row based on the store and the site that the user is currently logged into. If i run that select query when my store condition is true will it create a new row? Thanks.